# $a_1=3;\ a_{n+1}=3^{a_n}$; find $a_{2004}\bmod100$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A detailed solution will be helpful. Given that $a_1=3$ and $a_{n+1}=3^{a_n}$, find the remainder when $a_{2004}$ is divided by 100.

Comment: Please format your question properly...

Comment: Formatting hit: use curly braces { } to enclose more than one character intended as a subscript, as a_{n+1} to get $a_{n+1}$

Comment: If you want to write $a_{n+1}$ use the code a_{n+1}....make sure you enclose the $(n+1)$ part in double braces...

Comment: New to MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_1=3$$
$$a_2=3^3=27$$
$$a_3=3^{27}$$
Consider $a_4=3^{3^{27}}$. By Euler's theorem this is congruent to $3^{3^{27}\bmod40}$ modulo 100. Since $3^4\equiv1\bmod40$, $3^{27}\equiv3^3\equiv27\bmod40$. Thus we have the relation
$$3^{3^{27}}\equiv3^{27}\bmod100$$
In other words, exponentiating by 3 does not change the residue. Hence $a_n\equiv87\bmod100$ for $n\ge3$, and the answer is 87.

Comment: Sorry...but how did you get $3^{87}$?It should have been ${3^3}^{27}$?

Comment: @tatan $a_3\equiv87\bmod100$. I put this into the exponent for $a_4$'s calculation, and I get 87 again (mod 100).

Comment: You shouldn't use mod 100 in the exponent. Rather, use mod $\varphi(100)=40$. In this case, it doesn't go wrong, because you can also look mod $\gcd(\varphi(4),\varphi(25))=20$, which is a divisior of 100. Please clarify this issue in the answer.

Comment: @wythagoras Would you guide me how to fix the proof by using mod 20?

Comment: Observe that $3^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 100$. We get this form the Euler-Fermat theorem which gives $3^{\varphi(4)} =3^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $3^{\varphi(25)} =3^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 25$. This gives with the Chinese Remainder theorem that $3^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 100$. Now, we see that $3^{27} \equiv 3^7 \equiv 87 \mod 100$, and hence $3^{27} \equiv 3^7 \equiv 7 \mod 20$. Hence we have $3^{3^{27}} \equiv 3^{7} \equiv 87 \mod 100$ and $3^{3^{27}} \equiv 3^{7} \equiv 7 \mod 20$. In the same way, $a_i \equiv 87 \mod 100$ and  $a_i \equiv 7 \mod 20$ for all $i \geq 5$.

Comment: Alternatively, we get $3^{27} \equiv 27 \mod 40$, which gives $3^{3^{27}} \equiv 3^{27} \mod 100$, which is probably easier.

Comment: @wythagoras Incorporated your words into my answer. Does this fly?

Comment: Yeah, this works. By the way, you already have $3^4 \equiv 1 \mod 40$ (not that that matters, but you have to calculate less to see this)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $a_{2004} = 3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}}$ where the length of the exponent tower is $2003$. Anyway all we need to apply is Euler's Totient Formula. As $\phi(100) = 40$, so now we consider: $3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}} \bmod {40}$ where the tower length is $2002$. Continue in this manner and we will consider $\phi(40) = 16$, later on $\phi(16) = 8$.

Now we do a simple back tracking. As we know that $3$ to an odd exponent is equal to $3$ modulo $8$ we have: $3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}} \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. Then $3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}} \equiv 3^3 \equiv 11 \pmod{16}$. Then $3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}} \equiv 3^{11} \equiv 27 \pmod{40}$. And at the end:

$$a_{2004} = 3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}} \equiv 3^{27} \equiv 87 \pmod{100}$$

**NOTE:** For the exponents I used the same symbol, although the length of the tower varies, but I guess that should be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

By the CRT, in order to find $a_{2004}\pmod{100}$ it is enough to find $a_{2004}\pmod{8}$ and $a_{2004}\pmod{25}$. Now $a_n=3^{a_{n-1}}\pmod{8}$ just depends on $a_{n-1}\pmod{4}$, and $a_{n-1}=3^{a_{n-2}}\pmod{4}$ just depends on $a_{n-2}$ being even or odd. Since $a_{2002}$ is clearly odd, $a_{2003}\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $\color{green}{a_{2004}\equiv 3\pmod{8}}$. $a_n=3^{a_{n-1}}\pmod{25}$ just depends on $a_{n-1}\pmod{20}$. We already know that $a_{2003}\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, hence it is enough to find $a_{2003}=3^{a_{2002}}\pmod{5}$, or $a_{2002}\pmod{4}$. Since $a_{2002}\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, $a_{2003}\equiv 2\pmod{5}$, hence $a_{2003}\equiv 7\pmod{20}$ and $\color{green}{a_{2004}\equiv 12\pmod{25}}$. Putting together the green identities,
$$ \color{green}{\large a_{2004}\equiv 87\pmod{100}.}$$
You may notice that the above argument has little to do with the arithmetic properties of $2004$, and in fact you may apply the same argument to show that $a_n\equiv 87\pmod{100}$ for any $n\geq 3$.
This is due to the fact that by iterating the totient function, we always reach $1$ pretty soon.
For instance:
$$\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(100))))))=1.$$